# JSON parsed using NSJSONSerialization from JSON file returns an empty array

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I have a JSON file which I am trying to parse as seen below

```
-(void)loadSuraNames
{
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.submission.ws/downloads/json/"];

url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"quran_main.json"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil    error:nil];

NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

NSLog(@"my Json is empty :( %@", array);
}
```

But I am not getting any data back. Any one has any ideas what the problem is?

I am getting the following error:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid escape sequence around character 278.) UserInfo=0xa47ff60 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character 278.}

Comment: What does the error tell you? What is the data you are getting back?

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid escape sequence around character 278.) UserInfo=0xa47ff60 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character 278.}

Comment: Looks like you have some bad data. Always remember the recommended way to use NSError - see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON script was adding "/" characters that I manually removed and the problem is gone :)